# outerHeight() and height() give 0, after element is shown with "display: block" within an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a part of page, where I have 4 main divs, one of the divs has its height calculated depending on the heights of the other divs, and one of these other divs can disappear.

```
<div header></div>
<div divWithCalculatedHeight></div>
<div checkout></div>
<div disappearingDiv></div>
```

The way I am calculating the height of the 2nd div is pretty simple `totalHeight - $header.outerHeight() - $checkout.outerHeight() - $disappearingDiv.outerHeight()` and while all divs are visible this is working just fine. However I have buttons with events attached to them, that can make the 4th div disappear and appear back again. And this is my issue:

```
$buttonHide.trigger("hideFourthDiv")

$disappearingDiv.on("hideFourthDiv", () => { 
    $disappearingDiv.css({ display: "none" }); 
    calculateNew2ndDivHeightAndSetIt();
});
```

And this works just fine, but the reappearing:

```
$buttonShow.trigger("showFourthDiv")

$disappearingDiv.on("showFourthDiv", () => { 
    $disappearingDiv.css({ display: "block" }); // i have also tried with "initial"

    console.log($disappearingDiv.outerHeight()); // this here gives 0, so height of 2nd div cant be calculated properly

    calculateNew2ndDivHeightAndSetIt();
});
```

This here is my issue, when I make the div re-appear, while still inside the event, the `outerHeight()` returns `0`, I have also tried with `height()` it too returns `0`. Now it is important to note here that, if I click the button twice, on the second click it will work, which in a way coincides with my further thoughts:

Now, if click the `buttonShow` to trigger the showign event (just once!), and then I go into my browser `console` and manually type `$disappearingDiv.outerHeight()`, it does give me the correct height and not a 0!

So I thought that maybe, since I am still within the event, at that point in time, the DOM maybe is not yet updated, and jQuery doesnt see the "shown" element, so with that in mind I searched for a way to trigger my function outside of the event, once the div is shown and I found out about `MutationObserver`

So I tried implementing it:

```
const target = $disappearingDiv;
const config = { childList: true, subtree: true};
const callback = () => {console.log($disappearingDiv.height())};
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(target, config);
```

That code is not placed within any of the 2 events, it is inside the "DOMContentLoaded" event.

It does get triggered, when I hide/show, but it still gives me a 0 the first time I click the button.

So my question I am guessing is, how to manage to get the height of the `disappearingDiv` once it has reappered, from the first call of the events, so that I dont have to click the button two times.

**Edit:** I figured out what is the issue, but I can't find solution, when css is applied, it applies it inline, but the browser is not repainting immediatelly or whatever, that is why when I immediatelly check for height it is not yet available. I need to wait for the css of the element to be updated and then get the height. If I place the updating function within a timeout it will work with a timeout of as low as 1 ms. I have opened a new question after these new findings: [Wait for css of element to be updated when it is dynamically changed with JS/Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65448012/wait-for-css-of-element-to-be-updated-when-it-is-dynamically-changed-with-js-jqu)

Comment: are there any animations while showing the div?

Comment: @cagri nope, hiding is with display: none; and showign is with display: block; thats all

Comment: @cagri you may be on to something, because I tried with a timeout of 500 seconds now, and now I do get the height, so maybe there is something somewhere inherited.

Comment: I meant to say 500 miliseconds in my previous post, but I got it to work with a timeout of as low as 1 ms. Still that is not safe, and I can't figure out what is preventing the outerHeight from getting the height right after display is set to block.

Comment: I figured out what is the issue, but I can't find solution, when css is applied, it applies it inline, but the browser is not repainting immediatelly or whatever, that is why when I immediatelly check for height it is not yet available. I need to wait for the css of the element to be updated and then get the height.

Comment: Are you able to create a demo of your issue? That would help out in debugging.

Comment: Try using `hide()` and `show()` functions instead of `css()`

Comment: @firatozcevahir hide() and show() do the same thing, they set display to none and to block.

Comment: Yes but you can pass a function as a second parameter in `hide()` or `show()`  functions to get the height after hiding or showing finished.

Comment: @firatozcevahir yes .show({
      done: (res) => {
        res.then(() => {
          console.log($element.outerHeight());
        });
      },
    }); that did work, but I also found out that I can do setTimeout with 0 or just setTimeout(func) with no arguments and that simply schedules the function to run on the next event loop looping and that works too and seems a bit cleaner, but I'll see which one I'll end up using. You can add it as an answer and I will accept it since it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to wait for a render to happen before checking the height of the div. This would be doing something like using `setTimeout` but with waiting for the next render instead of waiting or `n` amount of milliseconds.

```
$disappearingDiv.on("showFourthDiv", () => { 
  $disappearingDiv.css({ display: "block" }); // i have also tried with "initial"
  
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    console.log($disappearingDiv.outerHeight()); // this here gives 0, so height of 2nd div cant be calculated properly.
    calculateNew2ndDivHeightAndSetIt();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesnt work (at least in my case, for some reason), however setTimeout with 0ms works.